# Installing and Deleting Input Languages using C# or VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows, winapi, input-language

Is there any way to install/delete input language in Windows using c# or VB?
I'm aware about `InputLanguage` class. But that doesn't provide functions to install/Delete input languages. Even if I change `CurrentInputLanguage` to any of `InstalledInputLanguages` that applies to my application only. I need to install/delete input languages in windows programmatically.

Comment: Look into Windows Shell api

Answer (score 1):

Your probably looking for a method to run power-shell inside your program, I'm not aware of a simple way to do what you want inside VB or C#, however configuring windows is what power shell is for.

Take a look at
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c.aspx

then look up how to install a language using power-shell.

so im guessing in power-shell you want something based on Set-WinUserLanguageList

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852168.aspx

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell script:

```
$LangList = Get-WinUserLanguageList
$EnLang = $LangList | where EnglishName -eq "English"
$LangList.Remove($EnLang)
Set-WinUserLanguageList $LangList -Force
```